# Multiple notification in a specific dates by using specific tutorial

Tags: android, notifications

I used this tutorial to make notification for specific date in my app: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time

Can I have multiple notification by saving user dates? and how?
I want to save dates in sqlite database and then use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple notification by only changing first parameter in this

```
 notificationManager.notify(UNIQUE_INT_NOTI_ID, notification);
```

that first parameter shows unique ID for notification so you can give your unique integer value into that or you can create like this using random:

```
Random random = new Random();
int UNIQUE_INT_NOTI_ID = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
```